# Root cannot remove file on ext4

Tags: permissions, filesystems, ext4

I have on ext4 disc the following file:

`-r--r--r-- 1 root root 61440 20. pro 15.30 ldlinux.sys`

But `rm`, `chmod` and `mv` says permission denied even for root. Any ideas what could be the problem?

FYI, it is file in boot sector of distro slax, but it is not used for booting. I just extracted the installation archive and I want to remove it.

Comment: Is your file system mounted `read-only (ro)`  What does `getfacl ldlinux.sys` tell you.  Where is this file located? What is it's absolute path?

Comment: What about `lsattr ldlinyx.sys`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably mistake somewhere. Either:

- You're trying to remove the file as unprivileged user,
- The file has file attributes: see them with `lsattr ldlinux.sys`,
- The directory you're trying to remove file from has file attributes, see them: `lsattr .` (in directory containing `ldlinux.sys`).

Other conditions may apply, for example readonly filesystem, but they usually generate errors other than permission denied.

Superuser can override any permission checks in the kernel, and file mode does not matter.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. It has attribute i (immutable). Solution: `chattr -i ldlinux.sys`

Comment: slight nitpick: extended attributes usually refers to the named attribute values used for selinux labels etc. (there's a man page xattr(5)) The not-so-usual permission bits like immutable are apparently called just "(file) attributes". Also they are somewhat filesystem specific: e.g. lsattr shows also flags like `I` and `e` for indexed directories and extent-format files, which are really just details about the filesystem implementation.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, you are right. I updated my answer. However there are other attributes which can deny root to delete files. I remember `i` and `a`.